# how do I give user ability to write code at runtime in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I would like to give the end user the ability to create small scripts like:

```
if value1 = 2 then
value2 = 1
end if
```

I want to do this within my vb.net winforms application to allow the user to compare values in the application DB and change values.  I have done some searching but I don't see much on the topic.

Thank you.

Comment: cant you write code to collect a value and an option for what to compare it to and do it for them?  What you want can be done using CodeDOM, but it assumes all sorts of things such as the user knowing the schema, programming and much more.

Comment: thank you.  I will look into CodeDOM.  I was hoping to include intellisense as well.  I am open to 3rd party controls as well.  I was using a simple example but I also need more complex functions like timers, for loops, while loops, etc.

Comment: sounds like the users need Visual Studio

Comment: good point Plutonix!  LOL.  It's assumed they are not programmers per se, but need simple scripting capability.  thanks for you input though!  it made me laugh.

Comment: using extended design analysis it may be possible to identify a set of algorithms, tables and formulae which will accommodate 80% of what they need.  Then they pick the method from a list, fill in the defined params, and your code then runs the selected procedure probably in a DLL (so it can be easily extended).

Comment: I like this idea.  It takes away most of the complexity but still lets me give the functionality I want.  Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

MS used to provide a VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) SDK, but that was tossed out in 2007. Then they came out with VSA (Visual Studio for Applications) and tossed it out when VS2005 came along. Now days, the only thing you can do to provide *real programming ability* is to write your own (Using C#, VBScript or some other languages) and then compile and execute it.

You're better off providing a simple interface where they can choose certain abilities (many applications call this an Expression Builder) and you have a bunch of cases to handle the features you allow.

For more info on VBA/VSA, see this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)

Answer (score -1):

You don't see much on this because it's not a good idea.  It's never a good idea to allow the end user the ability to create open-ended searches.  You've touched on one of the more difficult issues in software development...ad-hoc queries.

In short, your best bet is to find out what kind of queries the user will need and give them strongly-typed search criteria options to filter the result set to their needs.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying.  However users are creating objects within my application (entity framework), which they then need to be able to manipulate, check values for properties, and change values of properties, based on conditions, time, etc.